# The first transistors in space: Germanium or Silicon? What about in orbit?

Tags: history, electronics, spaceflight-firsts

Certain people (me) will have hours of fun in the [Transistor Museum](http://semiconductormuseum.com/Museum_Index.htm) website. Who can resist stuff like this: [Historic Germanium Transistors; General Transistor/General Instrument (5MB pdf)](http://semiconductormuseum.com/PhotoGallery/Photogallery_General_Transistor_General_Instrument_Historic_Germanium_Computer_Transistors.pdf)?

I found there a [book review of *Opening Space Research; Dreams, Technology, and Scientific Discovery*](http://semiconductormuseum.com/MuseumLibrary/Final_Transistor_Museum_Book_Review_Opening_Space_Research_by_George_Ludwig.pdf), Ludwig, George H., American Geophysical Union, Washington DC, 2011. (478pp), ISBN: 978-0-87590-733-8.

There I saw these photos, including a *thanks for the transistors!* note from James Van Allen to Texas Instruments. I believe these particular transistors are silicon, but it got me wondering:

**Question:** The first transistors in space: Germanium or Silicon? What about in orbit?

---

**below x2:** from the Transistor Museum's [book review](http://semiconductormuseum.com/MuseumLibrary/Final_Transistor_Museum_Book_Review_Opening_Space_Research_by_George_Ludwig.pdf) of *Opening Space Research; Dreams, Technology, and Scientific Discovery*.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: The 2N33X transistors were silicon transistors, see http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/134735/ASI/2N335.html

Comment: The TI900 were silicon transistors too, see http://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_ti900.html

Comment: @Uwe how did you get the radiomuseum to give you information on transistors? I typed [`CK722`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CK722) in the search box but couldn't get any transistor information.

Comment: Just use a good search machine. I prefer metager.de

Comment: @Uwe WOW I've been googling so long that I'd forgotten other search engines even exist! Yep it worked, and I also found there is even a ck722museum.com site as well, dedicated to... you guessed it, CK722! I found this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdVav.jpg in the [photo gallery](http://www.ck722museum.com/page13.html) I have the same one in a box of "stuff" somewhere.

Comment: companion question: [When was the last normal electron tube (valve) for electrical circuitry launched into space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21965/12102)

Comment: As addition about a first transistors in interplanetary space. http://mentallandscape.com/V_OKB1.htm

Comment: @A.Rumlin Excellent photo-synopsis of "Inventing The Interplanetary Probe", thanks!  fyi I've just asked [How were the Venera variometers able to measure extremely weak, nano-Tesla magnetic fields?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37553/12102)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first transistors in space (and in orbit) were likely germanium, and they were aboard Sputnik-2 in 1957, though Sputnik-2 did use vacuum tubes as well.

The first all-transistor satellite was Explorer 1, as explained by George Ludwig:

> **Was the Explorer I the first earth satellite to carry transistor electronics?**
>
> In my original interview I said that it was.  Since then, I researched the question and found that, although the Soviets did not use transistors in Sputnik I, Sputnik II, launched in November 1957, did use a few transistors in one of its instruments.  Of course they had a much larger launch capacity and could carry vacuum tubes and their required batteries.  The Explorer I launch occurred on January 31st local time, which was actually February l Greenwich time, of 1958.  It was the first all-transistor satellite.

Explorer 1 used a combination of germanium and silicon transistors.

Sputnik-2 and Explorer 1 were the second and third satellites to orbit Earth, respectively.

The first computer in space (and first computer in orbit) was the Gemini digital computer, built by IBM, which first flew in 1965. It was IBM's first completely silicon semiconductor computer.

**Sources:**

- [Sputnik-2 - Don P. Mitchell](http://mentallandscape.com/S_Sputnik2.htm)
- [A Transistor Museum Interview with Dr. George Ludwig - The First Transistors in Space - Personal Reflections by the Designer of the Cosmic Ray Instrumentation Package for the Explorer I Satellite - Page 5](http://semiconductormuseum.com/Transistors/LectureHall/Ludwig/Ludwig_Page5.htm)
- [A Transistor Museum Interview with Dr. George Ludwig - The First Transistors in Space - Personal Reflections by the Designer of the Cosmic Ray Instrumentation Package for the Explorer I Satellite - Index](http://semiconductormuseum.com/Transistors/LectureHall/Ludwig/Ludwig_Index.htm)
- [Computers in Spaceflight: The NASA Experience - Chapter One - The Gemini Digital Computer: First Machine in Orbit - Page 1 - NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/ch1-1.html)
- [Computers in Spaceflight: The NASA Experience - Chapter One - The Gemini Digital Computer: First Machine in Orbit - Page 2 - NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/Ch1-2.html)
- [Subsidizing Silicon: NASA and the Computer - Anthony J. Pennings](http://apennings.com/how-it-came-to-rule-the-world/the-cold-war/subsidizing-silicon-nasa-and-the-computer/)
- [Computers in Spaceflight: The NASA Experience - Chapter One - The Gemini Digital Computer: First Machine in Orbit - Page 5 - NASA](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/Ch1-5.html)

Comment: Ah, so do you think "When did the first *silicon* transistor orbit the Earth?" is answered clearly here or is there room for it be asked separately?

Comment: The first three satellites were Sputnik 1, Sputnik 2, and Explorer 1. It was established here that Sputnik 1 had no transistors and Explorer 1 had both germanium and silicon transistors. We do not know for sure what transistors were on the Sputnik 2, and we are unlikely to come by that information given the note on George Ludwig's interview: "(Curator’s note:  See reference [5] for a more detailed discussion of Sputnik 1 and 2 -  there is a reference to the use of  semiconductor triodes on Sputnik 2, **although there is not much published information on Soviet early transistor technology**)."

Comment: I've squeezed out a [follow-up question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21965/12102) I have a hunch you know the answer already.