# Syncom-3 was the first geostationary satellite. Anyone know of a description of the onboard electronics?

Tags: history, communication-satellite, geostationary, electronics, data-storage

I am interested in any description of the electronics on Syncom-3, the first geostationary satellite.  I've been able to find quite a bit of general information.  There was a pair of 2 Watt TWTs and somewhere there were five stages of clever diode frequency doubling to get up to the 7 GHz frequency. But I've not been able to find out if it was all vacuum tubes, for example, or if there were any transistors used.  Was there a computer or state-machine of any description? What type of memory elements (if any) were used. Latching relays, Core memory, etc.  These are the links I've seen so far:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncom
- https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1964-047A
- https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/syncom-1.htm
- http://web.archive.org/web/20101111082736/http://www.boeing.com/defense-space/space/bss/factsheets/376/syncom/syncom.html

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read this [technical report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19670015715.pdf) by NASA.

By searching "transistor" in the pdf, I have found this:

> [...] the  frequency  multiplication is accomplished  in  eight 
>   doublers,  of which all but the first involve the  use of varactor 
>   diodes  connected  push-push in  efficient duo-mode  networks.   The
>   first doubler uses a conventional transistor  circuit [...]

And this for "memory":

> A psi  tracker is used  in  the input circuitry of the  synchronous 
>   controller  servo.   This functions as a memory  circuit  to  ensure 
>   controller  lock-on if  for  some  reason  psi  pulses  from  the
>   spacecraft are lost.  It also  discriminates  against  noise  and 
>   spurious  signals  from  the  telemetry  receiver  that  might 
>   otherwise  break  controller lock-on.

(There were also other results for transistor and memory).

Comment: Very cool! (more info on early transistors in space: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21961/12102)

Comment: fyi I've just asked [How did Syncom-3 achieve eight stages of frequency doubling? I only see seven in the block diagram](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30198/12102)