# When did an astronaut in space first see someone on a TV screen?

Tags: history, astronauts, video, spaceflight-firsts

The Apollo missions had video cameras and transmitted live images to Earth. But what about the other direction -- *astronauts seeing live images of people on Earth?*

**Question:** When did an astronaut in space first see someone live on a TV or video screen or a computer monitor?

---

Related questions about electronic items in spaces (firsts or lasts):

- [The first transistors in space: Germanium or Silicon? What about in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21959/12102)
- [When was the last normal electron tube (valve) for electrical circuitry launched into space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21965/12102)

Comment: companion question: [Who was the first person in space to “be on TV”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37536/12102), and related in SciFi SE [Which author commented that “we all got it wrong” about walking on the moon being televised?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100155/51174)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://www.kik-sssr.ru/Duplex_Fobos.htm

> Двухсторонняя телевизионная связь впервые была установлена с  бортом ОПС "Салют-6". Космонавты Ляхов и Рюмин (3-я основная экспедиция, 8-я стыковка пилотируемых КК); прибывшие на "Союзе-32" (старт 25 февраля 1979 года), смонтировали ТВ-аппаратуру, присланную на "Прогрессе-5" (запущен 12-го и пристыкован 14 марта 1979 г.) и 24  марта 1979 года стали первыми телезрителями в космосе.

translation:

> Two-way television communication was first established with the Salyut-6 orbital station. Cosmonauts Lyakhov and Ryumin (3rd main expedition, 8th docking of manned spacecraft); those who arrived on Soyuz-32 (start on February 25, 1979), mounted TV equipment sent on Progress-5 (launched on 12th and docked on March 14, 1979) and on March 24, 1979 became the first television viewers in space .