# Who was the first person in space to "be on TV"?

Tags: apollo-program, astronauts, video, spaceflight-firsts

The Apollo missions had video cameras and transmitted live images to Earth, but I am not sure if there were any video transmission prior to the Apollo 11.

**Question:** Who was the first person in space to "be on TV", to have live video of them in space, transmitted to Earth? When was it and in what spacecraft did it happen?

Comment: To have a TV image of them transmitted from space? Shepard was on TV plenty before his flight.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes. I added a few words to make it clearer.

Comment: companion question: [When did an astronaut in space first see someone on a TV screen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37535/12102), and related in SciFi SE [Which author commented that “we all got it wrong” about walking on the moon being televised?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100155/51174)

Comment: You're forgetting the [Apollo 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sR0VI7dSksk) broadcast when they were half way to the Moon, December 22, 1968. The also broadcast a Christmas Eve message. Don't forge the book of Genesis quote broadcast. That got NASA into some trouble.

Comment: @Fred I've asked the question because I don't know; therefore I am not forgetting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yuri Gagarin, the first man in space. There was a real-time TV transmission from his spacecraft, the 'Vostok'.

Some fragments here:

edit by Hobbes: added screenshot of the in-flight video:
[image]

Comment: As addition "TV from Vostok" http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/trackind/TVostok/TVostok.htm