# First TTL chip in space and in orbit? Was it a 7400 series or something that predates?

Tags: electronics, computing, computer, spaceflight-firsts

Similarly to

- [The first transistors in space: Germanium or Silicon? What about in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21959/12102)
- [First LED left on another planet⁺ by humans?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46645/12102) w/list of space electronic "firsts" questions

what was the first [TTL proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) integrated circuit or chip in space (includes suborbital flights) and to orbit or beyond?

Was it a Texas Instruments [7400 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits) or something that predates those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to "Military Implications of the Transfer of Semiconductor Technology to the USSR", the Minuteman II used "monolithic TTL" integrated circuits
https://www.cia.gov/readingroom/docs/DOC_0000969810.pdf

These were likely custom TTL chips made by Texas Instruments, predating the military 5400 version of the 7400 family.

Whic ICBMs don't go into orbit ([well sometimes...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur_(rocket_family))), they definitely go into space in suborbital trajectories.

The first Minuteman II missile was launched September 24, 1964.

Comment: Gemini 1 was launched April 8 1964, 4 months earlier.

Comment: @Uwe But did it use TTL chips?

Comment: Gemini used RTL, Minuteman may have used  TTL gates from Sylvania made 1963.

Comment: Gemini used RTL logic built with discrete components, no chips.

Answer (score 9):

The Apollo guidance computer was built with [RTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic)  logic. RTL was followed by [DTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode%E2%80%93transistor_logic) and later by [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic).

The Apollo guidance computer used only a dual three input NOR gate.[image]

Integrated RTL logic was introduced 1961, DTL 1962 and TTL 1963.

The Gemini computer was built without integrated circuits, only discrete components, see [Computers in Spaceflight: The NASA Experience](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/Ch1-2.html).

The 5400 And gate was introduced 1964, the [7400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits#Overview) 1966. 5400 was the military temperature range, 7400 the commercial range.

So the first logic chip used in space was RTL, not TTL.

Comment: Helpful picture: http://static.righto.com/images/agc-rope/nor-schematic.png

Comment: @DrSheldon: I wonder why the schematic is drawn with the pins in that order?  If one were to draw the schematic with pins in order 10-1-2-3-4-5 counter-clockwise on the left side, and 5-6-7-8-9-10 on the right, the pinout would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @supercat: It is rather odd.  They could have done a better job conveying the symmetry of the chip.  The power pins (5 and 10) should appear only once, and connect the two sides.

Comment: @supercat and @ DrSheldon Pinout was not that odd. It should be possible to use the gate as a NOR gate with two inputs by grounding an unused input. Connecting pin 4 to pin 5 GND was easy using adjacent pins, same with pin 6 to 5. If  an inverter was needed, the pins 3, 4 and 5 were connected. A noninverting buffer was achieved by connecting pin 2 to 9 and ground all  unused inputs by a connection of pins 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. The pinout should avoid additional metallization layers on the chip and additional vias or wire bridges on the printed circuit boards.

Comment: @DrSheldon For a really odd pinout look for 74LS273 compared to 74LS373. If they would have done it right in the first try, there would be no 74LS273 at all.

Comment: @Uwe: I meant the way that they *drew* it is non-symmetrical, not the actual pinout.

Comment: @DrSheldon There is a convention for drawing circuits: inputs and transistor base to the left, outputs and transistor emitter and collector to the right. If symmetric circuits like [current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror) or this [flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TTL_flip-flop.svg) are drawn, inputs may be drawn to the right too. But when a flip flop is drawn using gates symbols like the NAND latch, the NOR latch or the AND - OR latch, all inputs are drawn to the left, see [flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics).

Comment: @Uwe: Swapping pins 10 and 1 on the left side to match the physical orientation and extending the common-emitter wire on the right side leftward would have allowed the two pin-10 connections to be adjacent, and likewise the two pin-1 connections, even if all the transistor orientations were left alone.

Comment: @supercat  Swap pins 10 and 1 on the left side would be a violation of the rule: outputs to the right! Readability of the schematics is much better when those rules are followed as strict as possible. Pin 5 and 10 exist only one time for both gates, so it is possible to draw those pins on one side only.

Comment: @Uwe: Power and ground pins are only inputs and outputs if a device is intended to respond to changes in the power that's available to a device, or control the flow of current to other devices.  As for the "rule", it's a guideline which is followed when there is no compelling reason to favor one direction over the other, but which often gives way to other considerations.

Answer (score 5):

According to [*Computers in Spaceflight*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19880069935), the **Voyager Attitude Articulation and Control System Computer**.

> Dubbed "HYPACE," for Hybrid Programmable Attitude Control Electronics, it
> was a byte-serial processor with substantial power. Using the same
> 4K, 18-bit-wide plated-wire memory from the Viking Orbiter computer, HYPACE added **transistor-transistor logic (TTL)** medium-scale
> integrated circuits to create a relatively fast (28-microsecond cycle)
> processor with index registers for addressing. Byte-serial architecture
> was possible because the TTL chips were designed for 4-bit parallel
> operation, so the 18-bit words could be moved around in five cycles
> instead of the 18 a serial machine would need, increasing overall
> speed. Index registering meant that the same block of code could be
> used for all three axes, reducing memory requirements. It appeared
> that the attitude control systems of future spacecraft would almost certainly benefit from such a computer.
> **Voyager was the first to do so, due to new requirements.**
>
> p. 177

---

The program for the Apollo Guidance Computer was woven into core rope memory.  Because this was a very labor-intensive process, a simulator replaced the core memory unit while the software was being developed.  This [simulator used 7400-series TTL logic](http://www.righto.com/2019/07/apollo-guidance-computer-dipstiks-and.html), although it never actually flew in space.