# First multiprocessor in space?

Tags: electronics, spaceflight-firsts, computer

Similarly to

- The first [transistors](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21959/the-first-transistors-in-space-germanium-or-silicon-what-about-in-orbit) in space: Germanium or Silicon? What about in orbit?
- First [LED](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/first-led-left-on-another-planet%e2%81%ba-by-humans) left on another planet⁺ by humans? w/list of space electronic "firsts" questions
- First [TTL](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54100/first-ttl-chip-in-space-and-in-orbit-was-it-a-7400-series-or-something-that-pre) chip in space and in orbit? Was it a 7400 series or something that predates?

which mission used the first multiprocessor in space?

The Saturn V rocket control computer used three processors executing the same program to increase reliability by redundancy.

This question is about the first distributed computing in space, several independent digital processors executing different programs within a single space probe. General purpose processors with a memory for data and program.

Comment: You'll need to define *processor*.  Early vehicles had a *lot* of modules dedicated to processing specific analog or digital signals, and also sequencers, which may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

The first space probe using distributed computing was Voyager:

> **Voyager employs three dual-redundant computer systems per
> spacecraft.** The first, the CCS, is nearly identical to that flown on
> Viking, performing sequencing and spacecraft health functions along
> with new ones necessitated by the addition of the other computers.
> Telemetry data formatting and transmission handled by the Flight
> Data System are done on Voyager with the help of a custom-built
> computer. Attitude control and articulation of the scan platform are
> accomplished with the third computer system. One concept from the
> STAR computer proposed for the TOPS, applicable to Voyager, is
> longer dormancy. if unpowered JPL's pro B
> ect . Although staff believed both CCSs that equipment are always would powered,
> last
> rarely are both Flight Data Systems running, and both attitude control
> computers are never turned on at the same time. Full bit-for-bit redun-
> dancy is not maintained in the dual memories. For example,
> "expended" algorithms, such as the deployment sequence executed
> shortly after separation from the booster, need not be maintained5.
> Both memories are accessed by the single active processor in each
> system. The Flight Data System keeps a copy of its instructions in
> both memories, but intermediate data and variables can be stored in
> either memory. This seemingly casual attitude toward memory
> duplication tightens up considerably near encounter periods, which is
> one time that both CCS processors are in tandem mode.
>
> Source: [*Computers in Spaceflight*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19880069935), p. 174